# My vue-router won't load the component when I fresh load a page, but loads when I transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header-section />
    <router-view class="child-container" />
    <bottom-nav v-if="!isAuthRoute" />
  </div>
</template>
```

My router.js:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'Authenticate',
        component: Authenticate,
    }, {
        path: 'conversations',
        name: 'ConversationsList',
        component: ConversationsList
    }, {
        path: 'conversations/:ConversationId',
        component: ConversationDetail,
        children: [{
            path: '',
            name: 'ConversationDetailHighlights',
            component: ConversationDetailHighlights

        }, {
            path: 'transcript',
            name: 'ConversationDetailFullTranscript',
            component: ConversationDetailFullTranscript

        }]
    }],

    scrollBehavior() {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
});
```

When I click a link to go to `/conversations`, it loads fine. But when I load `/conversations` straight in the browser, it doesn't load the `ConversationsList` component:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with `path: '/conversations'`? I'm pretty sure the slash prefix is omitted only if the route is a child of the the `path: '/'`'s route

Comment: That did it - please add as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `path: '/conversations'`? I'm pretty sure the slash prefix is omitted only if the route is a child of the the `path: '/'`'s route